# should the size of polygons of a 3d model be the same?

Tags: vertices, edges, faces, topology

I recently learned from my previous question, that it's better make faces with 4 verts.

It really helped me with lots of things, unwraping, texturing, etc.

To reduce the poly counts of my models, I tried removing the unnecassary verts without turning any 4 vert face to n-gone.

But I don't know if it's OK from a professional perspective.

Please take a look at the image below.

[image]

M question is, can the polygons of a 3d model have different sizes? not slightly different, the difference between the size of the faces of my model is huge. i personally thought it's cool and fine but wanted to know some professionals opinion.

Thanks for reading my question,

Best regards.

Comment: it's ok not to have the same size, create edge loops only if necessary

Comment: Do you plan on using subdivision on your mesh or are you going low-poly ?

Comment: @Gorgious the image that I've uploaded in my question also has subdivision surface modifier on it. but my question is about the whole idea of removing some unnessesary edges to reduce the poly count, i wanted to know if that OK.
i have also removed some of the edges from my high poly models, they look ok to me.

Comment: @moonboots so, it's better to remove all the unnessesary edges from my models. as long as it doesn't ruin the shape right?

Comment: @Amirreza Moeini Yegane exactly, only bring edge loops if it's useful

Comment: @moonboots awesome, thank you for your time. would you please write an answer so i can accept it? you answered my question the best way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to care about keeping the same size for all the quads, a topology doesn't need to be homogeneous, only bring edge loops when it's useful, delete all the ones that don't bring anything to the shape, you'll save calculation and your object will be easier to work.

For example look at this topology: You have small quads around the lips, they are bigger around the forehead, and even bigger around the shoulders, because it's exactly what's necessary for these parts, no more, no less.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, the answer couldn't be better than this

Comment: There is one thing to note however, depending on your use of application a large face might look ugly in a render depending on how the normal of that face is setup.  Sometimes subdividing it might actually help give better result.

Comment: @Sidar thanks for this tip, so in case a large face became ugly in rendering, i'll try to subdivide it :-) . however, moonboots said, **only remove the edges if they don't bring anything to the mesh**.

Comment: @AmirrezaMoeiniYegane Keeping your mesh clean is good practice yes, but in any case  shading looks off, it's probably because it needs more detail to get proper shading going. This might likely be more of a thing in Eevee instead of Cycles

Comment: @Sidar it's a pretty good thing to know. Because if it happens, it can cause headache and consume our time. thanks you for explaining.